# Where to raise a typo in the PyTorch Documentation?

Tags: pytorch

I have found a typo in the official PyTorch Documentation. Where can I raise the flag so that it is rectified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [PyTorch Contribution Guide](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/community/contribution_guide.html#pytorch-contribution-guide), in the [section](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/community/contribution_guide.html#improving-documentation-tutorials) on Documentation:

> Improving Documentation & Tutorials
>
> We aim to produce high quality documentation and tutorials. On rare
> occasions that content includes typos or bugs. If you find something
> you can fix, send us a pull request for consideration.